# How to extract minimum and maximum dates from string with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to extract minimum and maximum dates from a string column in pandas. I have two string formats to extract dates.

First one is:

```py
date_from_string = 'My date format is 7-20 November 2019'
```

And the second one is:

```py
date_from_string_v2 = 'My date format is 7 October and 7 November 2019'
```

I want to extract minimum and maximum dates seperately. For example, for the first case:

```py
minimum_date = 20191107
maximum_date = 20191120
```

or for the second type:

```py
minimum_date = 20191007
maximum_date = 20191107
```

I have tried a `date_converter` function code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172921/parse-through-text-and-extract-dates-in-uniform-format). I also tried `dateutils` and `datefinder` modules. But I could not solve this yet. I need some help for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You have mixed up your extraction examples. Please correct. First extraction wrongly refers to second example **and** what's more, has mistake in month. It is very confusing to read something like that. Also, don't refer us to another question, but show your problematic actual code.

Comment: Check these modules out : [parsedatetime](https://pypi.org/project/parsedatetime/), [date-extractor](https://pypi.org/project/date-extractor/), [datefinder](https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/).

Comment: Are these two examples the only cases? Or is it possible that date comes in any other format as well? Are there any fixed string sequences which will be present in any input string (eg can you rely on there being text "My date format is "?

Comment: Dear @Gnudiff, "My date format is..." is only example but, my string data includes dates in two types "...7-20 November 2019" and "...7 October and 7 November 2019". When I try the solutions above, I can only parse one date or more dates as "datetime.datetime(...)" format.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, if a string includes just one case and just a single range of dates, a regex could possibly be better than date parser. Date parsers are usually geared at producing a single date, not a range (maybe one of the modules Arkistarvh mentioned does ranges, but I doubt it).

A regex targeted at the strings you supplied would be something like this:

```
re_month=r'(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)'

re_ranges=r'(?P<range1s>\d{1,2})-(?P<range1e>\d{1,2} +'+re_month+' +\d{4})|(?P<range2s>\d{1,2} +'+re_month+') +and +(?P<range2e>\d{1,2} +'+re_month+' +\d{4})'

#which gives:

>re.search(re_ranges,date_from_string).groups()
('7', '20 November 2019', None, None)
>re.search(re_ranges,date_from_string_v2).groups()
(None, None, '7 October', '7 November 2019')
```

which can then be parsed by normal date parsers.